# pandas.read_csv() fails on na-values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

From my point of view in the code below I explicit declared `-` as a na-value (or missing) for an `int32` column while reading a csv file.

But I got the error message

```
ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 2
```

So it looks like that pandas recognize the `-` as a na value but treat it like an error. But it should just interpret it as a na-value because I defined it that why. Why doesn't it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

# there is a missing/empty value in 4th row
csv_data = """idx;FOO;BAR\n
zero;0;-\n
eins;one;2\n
zwei;two;3\n"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data),
                 header=0,
                 sep=';',
                 dtype={'BAR': 'int32'},
                 na_values={'BAR': '-'})

print(df)
```

A workaround could be to tread the columns all as strings and convert them after `read_csv()`. But that is not the kind of solution I am looking here for. I assume I missunderstand the options of `read_csv()`?

Comment: change `dtype={'BAR': 'Int32'}` (with upper case 'I'). `int32` does not support `na` values. `Int32` is a [nullable type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try changing `int32` to `Int32` (uppercase `I` letter), it must be like this:

```
dtype={'BAR': 'Int32'}
```

The uppercase version of that dtypes supporting `na` values.

Then I strogly recommend to use `np.nan` insted of `-`.